# Function with many lines that takes image as parameter not returning same result as if I run the same lines of code

Tags: functions, image

Running the exact same lines of code in a function produces just a return of the original image without any points identified, whereas when I run the exact body of the function line by line it works consistently. Is something wrong with my function?

```
points[img_] := (src = ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"];
white = Closing[src, DiskMatrix[5]];
srcAdjusted = Image[ImageData[src]/ImageData[white]]; 
components = 
ComponentMeasurements[
 ColorNegate@Binarize[srcAdjusted], {"ConvexArea", "Mask"}][[All, 
2]];
largestComponent = Image[SortBy[components, First][[-1, 2]]];
mask = FillingTransform[Closing[largestComponent, 2]];
lY = ImageMultiply[
MorphologicalBinarize[
 GaussianFilter[srcAdjusted, 3, {2, 0}], {0.02, 0.05}], mask];
lX = ImageMultiply[
MorphologicalBinarize[
 GaussianFilter[srcAdjusted, 3, {0, 2}], {0.02, 0.05}], mask]; 
verticalGridLineMasks = 
SortBy[ComponentMeasurements[
   lX, {"CaliperLength", "Centroid", "Mask"}, # > 100 &][[All, 
  2]], #[[2, 1]] &][[All, 3]];
horizontalGridLineMasks = 
SortBy[ComponentMeasurements[
   lY, {"CaliperLength", "Centroid", "Mask"}, # > 100 &][[All, 
  2]], #[[2, 2]] &][[All, 3]];
centerOfGravity[l_] := 
 ComponentMeasurements[Image[l], "Centroid"][[1, 2]]
gridCenters = 
 Table[centerOfGravity[
   ImageData[Dilation[Image[h], DiskMatrix[2]]]*
    ImageData[Dilation[Image[v], DiskMatrix[2]]]], {h, 
   horizontalGridLineMasks}, {v, verticalGridLineMasks}];
Show[src, 
 Graphics[{Red, 
 MapIndexed[{Point[#1], Text[#2, #1, {1, 1}]} &, 
  gridCenters, {2}]}]])
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Post the actual code by editing the question copying and pasting it into the  question.  Use the code button `{}` to format it.  Also use the image button to upload the image to the question. No one is going to retype your code so you need to provide it for copy and paste.

Comment: You need a semicolon after ComponentMeasurements and before gridcenters. Also, it doesn't make a lot of sense to define the centerofGravity function inside the points function.